# How to use ssh identity file with Github Actions

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I'm in the throes of setting up a Github Action that should run an SSH command to connect to a private server. The private server's connection settings i have specify an identityFile, which I do own. After this connection, I will then run a proxycommand, so this is essentially to a bastion, for context.

What I cannot quite figure out at this point is how/which github action supports this configuration. I see the commands on this one (similar to others): https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/blob/master/action.yml and no mention of identifyFile property. Is there another way to execute this or a ssh command that can make this possible?

Would appreciate some pointers, thanks!

Comment: #1 Do you need just execute ssh commands or scrips on remote server using github action? #2 identifyFile is mandatory? #3 Why https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action does not works for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you need some explanation of how to write your action, you can read this article : [How to create Github Actions to run tests with docker services](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-github-actions-to-run-tests-with-docker-services-ive-been-digging-github-actions-si-bk1133ye) .

You just have to create your workflow file and use the actions of appleboy like on `steps` keyword :

```
 - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
   uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
   with:
     host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
     username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
     key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
     key_path: ${{ secrets.KEY_PATH }}
     password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
     port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
     script: whoami
```

With the script line, you can execute what you want to do in the server and connect with the parameters set above. For multiple line do like this :

```
  script: |
    pwd
    ls -al
```

Hope it will help.